# How is handleChange receiving props? React

Tags: reactjs

I know it might be a similar question. But I cannot seem to find its solution. The code works perfectly fine. Whenever onChange function gets called. It is receiving selectionOption as props. But what are we passing in our this.handleChange? I tried passing e.target.value but it doesn't work. How is this code working?  For example this is something im trying to implement to understand its logic. onChange = {(e)=>this.handleChange(e.target.value)}. But this doesnt work.

**Example.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "react-select/dist/react-select.css";
import { stateOptions } from "./docs/data";

const options = [
  { value: "alabama", label: "Alabama" },
  { value: "florida", label: "Florida" },
  { value: "idaho", label: "Idaho" },
  { value: "washington", label: "Washington" },
  { value: "illinois", label: "Illinois" },
  { value: "vermont", label: "Vermont" }
];

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: ""
  };

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    // selectedOption can be null when the `x` (close) button is clicked
    if (selectedOption) {
      console.log(`Selected: ${selectedOption.label}`);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <Select
        multi={true}
        name="colors"
        value={selectedOption}
        // what are we sending in this handleChange and how?
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={stateOptions}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// what are we sending in this handleChange and how?
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

Your code is not in charge of that. It's up to react-select to pass a value in, and they do so on [this line of code in their code base](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/Select.tsx#L892):

```
onChange(newValue, actionMeta);
```

So react-select passes in the new value as the first argument, and something called actionMeta as the second argument. All you need to do is tell react-select what function it should send that data to, which you do with the code `onChange={this.handleSelect}`

Answer (score 0):

The string in the "value" field is passed.

Your handle function should expect a string:

```
 handleChange = selectedOption(newValue:string) => {
   //do something with this value here
  };
```

in this case the value corresponds to the "value" here:

```
const options = [
  { value: "alabama", label: "Alabama" },
  { value: "florida", label: "Florida" },
  { value: "idaho", label: "Idaho" },
  { value: "washington", label: "Washington" },
  { value: "illinois", label: "Illinois" },
  { value: "vermont", label: "Vermont" }
];
```